# PHP multiple buttons and if statements

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, if-statement

So i am no PHP guru and i have barely coded in it (mostly HTML changes inside a PHP script). I have a basic setup on the page i am working on.

The page has 4 buttons, they are all sending an email report to our service desk email to report any printer issues in our print labs. I have the email sending working and coded. The issue is that each button has to submit a different coded email to the service desk.

I have the four buttons as images (not a lot of people like the boring normal buttons) here is the code:

```
<form action="" method="post">

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h2>Please select issue</h2>
    <br/>


    <input type="image" src="testing/images/need_toner.png"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="toner" id="toner" tabindex="1" />
    <input type="image" src="testing/images/paper_jam.png" /><br>&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="paper-jam" id="paper-jam" tabindex="2" /><input type="image" src="testing/images/printer_fault.png" />
    <input type="hidden" name="printer-fault" id="printer-fault" tabindex="3" />
    <input type="image" src="testing/images/other.png" />
    <input type="hidden" name="other" id="other" tabindex="4"  />

</form>
```

So the buttons come out fine and look good and all that but when you click on any of the buttons it only executes the first PHP if code and ignores to check the others.
Here is my PHP code (keep in mind i am not really a PHP person, i just know some general coding.

```
<?php

    $url = 'testing/floor4/marketing'; // Setting the URL parameter for PHP

if(isset($_REQUEST['toner']))
{   

    $to      = 'XXX@XXX.com';
    $subject = 'TONER NEEDED - AKRON_32 Marketing Printer';
    $message = 'A request for toner has been reported for printer AKRON_32 on the 4th floor in the marketing department.';
    $headers = 'From: XXX@XXX.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: XXX@XXX.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


    header('Refresh: 6;URL=testing/floor4/marketing' );
    echo '<center><h2>Report Sent! - Page will refresh after a few seconds.</h2></center>';  

}

if(isset($_REQUEST['printer-fault']))
{
    $to      = 'XXX@XXX.com';
    $subject = 'PRINTER FAULT - AKRON_32 Marketing Printer';
    $message = 'A printer fault has been reported for printer AKRON_32 on the 4th floor in the marketing department.';
    $headers = 'From: XXX@XXX.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: XXX@XXX.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    header('Refresh: 6;URL=testing/floor4/marketing' );
    echo '<center><h2>Report Sent! - Page will refresh after a few seconds.</h2></center>';
}


if(isset($_POST['paper-jam']))
{
    $to      = 'XXX@XXX.com';
    $subject = 'PAPER JAM - AKRON_32 Marketing Printer';
    $message = 'A paper jam has been reported for printer AKRON_32 on the 4th floor in the marketing department.';
    $headers = 'From: XXX@XXX.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: XXX@XXX.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    header('Refresh: 6;URL=testing/floor4/marketing' );
    echo '<center><h2>Report Sent! - Page will refresh after a few seconds.</h2></center>';
}


if(isset($_POST['other']))
{
    $to      = 'XXX@XXX.com';
    $subject = 'OTHER  - AKRON_32 Marketing Printer';
    $message = 'An issue marked "other" has been reported for printer AKRON_32 on the 4th floor in the marketing department.';
    $headers = 'From: XXX@XXX.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: XXX@XXX.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    header('Refresh: 6;URL=testing/floor4/marketing' );
    echo '<center><h2>Report Sent! - Page will refresh after a few seconds.</h2></center>';
}

?>
```

So the code isn't the best structured i am sure so if you can help me out that'd be awesome, like i said i am no PHP coder. It's just weird how i originally had the coding working fine before i changed the echo text and had it redirect the headers no it just ONLY executes the first email for toner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_REQUEST['toner']` refers to `<input type="hidden" name="toner" id="toner" tabindex="1" />`. Since all the inputs are in the same form, this one is always sent, hence the first part of the code is always executed.

You should add a `name` attribute to your `<input type="image" />` elements :

```
<input type="image" name="img_need_toner" src="testing/images/need_toner.png"/>
<input type="hidden" name="toner" id="toner" tabindex="1" />
<input type="image" name="img_paper_jam" src="testing/images/paper_jam.png" /><br>
<input type="hidden" name="paper-jam" id="paper-jam" tabindex="2" />
<input type="image" name="img_printer_fault" src="testing/images/printer_fault.png" />
<input type="hidden" name="printer-fault" id="printer-fault" tabindex="3" />
<input type="image" name="img_other" src="testing/images/other.png" />
<input type="hidden" name="other" id="other" tabindex="4"  />
```

Keeping in mind that [clicking on an `<input type="image" />` will send the `x` and `y` coordinates of the click](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_height_width), you'll need to check for `$_POST['img_need_toner_x']` and `$_POST['img_need_toner_y']` (if you click on the first image).

Comment: I'm not trying to sound dumb or anything but only the first image button would need to use the x and y?
I've never really done anything like this before so i am just trying to gather more info on this so i can understand a little better and get it working.

Comment: As long as you add a `name` attribute on an `<input type="image">`, you're gonna need to check for its x and y. For example, if you click on the second image, you'll need to check for `$_POST['img_paper_jam_x']` and `$_POST['img_paper_jam_x']`, and so on.

Comment: Alright that kinda makes sense then, this is just all different to me. I'll change up the script here in a little and make sure it's all good.

Comment: Sooo...not sure why but the page is just a white page. All of the links to the images are good but the page is just white with nothing. The only error's i am seeing is just php unable to load mcrypt, nothing else.

The if is like this:
if(isset($_POST['img_need_toner_x'] and $_POST['img_need_toner_y']))

Comment: Nevermind i got it figured out!

Thank you so much buddy.
@Paul I'm sorry i couldn't give you the answered solution i tried roberto06's first and his worked first as well, thank you both though!

Answer (score 2):

All of you inputs are inside the same form tag so all inputs are being sent as set. There's a few things you could do, not sure why you are using $_REQUEST to be honest.

A quick fix and a way to give you a slightly better understanding would be to separate them into 4 separate forms and add NAME attributes and VALUE on your hidden fields. Then check the $_POST array for what the value(VALUE) of the error(NAME) is. See my example below.

```
<?php
$url = 'testing/floor4/marketing'; // Setting the URL parameter for PHP

if(isset($_POST['error'])){

    $error = $_POST['error'];

    if($error === 'toner' ){echo 'TONER ERROR';}
    if($error === 'paper-jam' ){echo 'PAPER JAM';}
    if($error === 'printer-fault' ){echo 'PRINTER FAULT';}
    if($error === 'other' ){echo 'OTHER';}
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>


<h2>Please select issue</h2>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="image" src="testing/images/need_toner.png"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="error" value="toner" id="toner" tabindex="1" />
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="image" src="testing/images/paper_jam.png" />
    <input type="hidden" name="error" value="paper-jam" id="paper-jam" tabindex="2" />
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="image" src="testing/images/printer_fault.png" />
    <input type="hidden" name="error" value="printer-fault" id="printer-fault" tabindex="3" />
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="image" src="testing/images/other.png" />
    <input type="hidden" name="error" value="other" id="other" tabindex="4"  />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

There is a lot more tidying up you could do that would be cleaner and there's hundreds of ways to do things in PHP e.g you could use radio buttons for each error and have them all on one form and if you didn't want a submit button you could use JavaScript to submit the form when a radio button is pressed. That's just one of many possibilities.

Comment: So i tried your code on a new test page and copied over the mail code and all that and this seems to send all of the emails and echo all of the buttons when you click any of them. Yeah my code is pretty messy because i just started throwing snippets together from sites i found haha.